# SQLite DateTime columns accepting any value... normal?

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I have an iOS app that takes use of SQLite. I use FireFox and the plugin SQLite Manager for managing the database.

Now I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "someTable" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL , "timeOfEvent" DATETIME NOT NULL)
```

I am however able to input practically any value I want into the DateTime column like so:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, timeOfEvent) VALUES (1,'2012-99-99')
INSERT INTO sometable (id, timeOfEvent) VALUES (2,'yyyy-mm-dd')
...etc
```

Why is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation: [SQLite- Data Types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> SQLite **does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates** and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT as ISO8601 strings**
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the  proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Thus SQLite relies on methods to convert the values. It doesn't have it's own data type to restrict date/time type.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I was updating but that human check comes in between.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is dynamic. From [SQLite Query Language - CREATE TABLE](http://sqlite.com/lang_createtable.html)

> Unlike most SQL databases, SQLite does not restrict the type of data that may be inserted into a column based on the columns declared type. Instead, SQLite uses dynamic typing. The declared type of a column is used to determine the affinity of the column only.